# Which Event Handler is called first?

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Imports ComponentAndControl

Public Class Form1

    Delegate Function Compare1(ByVal intNumber1 As Integer, ByVal intNumber2 As Integer) As Boolean
    Public Event e()
    Public Event e2(ByVal o As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim Test As New TestEventArgs
        Test.Name = "Bert"
        Test.Age = 34

        RaiseEvent e2(Me, Test)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestHandler4(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As TestEventArgs) Handles Me.e2
        MsgBox(e.Name)
        MsgBox(e.Age)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestHandler5(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As TestEventArgs) Handles Me.e2
        MsgBox(e.Name)
        MsgBox(e.Age)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Name As String
    Public Age As Integer

End Class
```

Which event handler is called first? I.e. TestEventHandler4 or TestEventHandler5? Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: Doesn't make sense in your example why you would have two event methods for the same event.  Where in your code would this be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event order when invoking a MultiCastDelegate is undefined in the .Net specification. They are typically invoked in the order they are added, in code order in your case, but don't rely on it.

---

*UPDATE*

This MSDN article seems to indicate that the invocation order is now guaranteed to be the order they were added.  I haven't actually verified this in practice, and I'm not sure what order Auto wireup events are added.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I thought it was code order to begin with, but I have found this is not the case.  I do not rely on the order; I was just curious.  Do you have any links to support your claim?